# WCF Service Not Updating (Multi project, same solution)

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm having a bit of trouble getting my WCF service reference from project A to reflect changes in project B.

I have both the service reference and a standard reference to the DLL of the service reference project.

When making changes to the service library, these changes are not propogated, it would seem, to my client application. Here is an example:

This is an example of one class that I just updated with a new 'test' constructor, that resides in the service library:

```
[DataContract]
    public class TransactionUploadResult {
        [DataMember]
        public string Transaction_ID;
        [DataMember]
        public bool Error;

        public TransactionUploadResult(string id, string temp, bool error) {
            Transaction_ID = id;
            Error = error;
        }

        public override string ToString() {
            return "TID:" + Transaction_ID + ", " + (Error ? "ERROR" : "SUCCESS");
        }
    }
```

Notice the superfluous second parameter 'temp' in the constructor.

Now here is a snippet from my client code (in a different project, same solution):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            TransactionUploadResult tur = new TransactionUploadResult("test", true);
            MessageBox.Show(tur.ToString());
            MessageBox.Show(RemoteHandler.ServiceClient.UploadTransaction(new Transaction()).ToString());
        }
```

UploadTransaction() returns a TransactionUploadResult. The MessageBoxes both show standard ToString() results for user-defined objects, NOT the ones I have defined in TransactionUploadResult.

The fact that the client even compiles and runs (considering it's using an outdated constructor) surprises me.

What's going wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just to be sure: Did you check the ServiceReference config setting "Reuse types in all referenced assemblies" ?

Comment: It is checked, yes, what does that do?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to right click on the service reference in the client application and choose "update service reference".

Comment: Ah, apologies, I ought to have mentioned that, but I have been doing this.

Comment: Only other solutions i can think of is making sure that the dll is built (clean/build) and making sure the datacontract matches the class that implements it, usually the datacontract is just an interface with the method signatures then you have a class that implements that interface and has the meat inside the methods.